# Div does not take full height

Tags: html, css, height

I 'm building a very minimal wordpress theme.
I just can' t figure out why my main-wrapper div does not take full height as it should. So my footer is displaying in the middle of the page with or without position absolute.

the website is this:
[www.davideasquini.com](http://www.davideasquini.com)

Thanks in advance for those who will help

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

CSS:

For main wrapper:

```
.main-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 95px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    display: table;
}
```

For footer:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0px 25px 0px;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: i solved by just not declaring height for .main-wrapper, and deleting position for footer...thanks for answering anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the footer always showing at the bottom of screen, change the CSS attribute of the footer element from `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`.

If you just want the footer displaying at the bottom of the document, remove `position: absolute` of the footer element and the `height:100%` of the body element.

The reason why your footer is displaying in the middle of the page with the footer set to `position:absolute` is because the containing block of the footer is established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute', 'relative' or 'fixed', since there is no such ancestor, the containing block is the viewport, so when you scroll the page up, the footer would display in the middle of the page.

See [containing block details](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)